# I have problem in using the drag function in testcafe

Tags: drag-and-drop, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am using testcafe for my end to end testing. I am currently testing my slider component and use the drag function, but for some reason it is not moving even though it shows the cursor moving.

This is my rough code:

```
const slider = Selector('#slider');
const sliderThumb = Selector('#slider-thumb');

test('Dragging Slider', async t => {
    await t
        .expect(slider.value).eql('50')
        .drag(sliderThumb, 30, 0)
        .expect(slider.value).eql('70');
});
```

I expect the slider thumb to move, but it is not moving. Any tips will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It is hard to say what is going on without the tested page. Could you please provide it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a `.click('#i-tried-testcafe');` after the await.

```
const slider = Selector('#slider');
const sliderThumb = Selector('#slider-thumb');

test('Dragging Slider', async t => {
    await t
        .click('#i-tried-testcafe');
        .expect(slider.value).eql('50')
        .drag(sliderThumb, 30, 0)
        .expect(slider.value).eql('70');
});
```

For more information: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/drag-element.html